# More space between lines in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` with about 10 rows. I want to have the lines more separated from each other. I can't seem to find an attribute for doing that. I tried with: `android:includeFontPadding="true"` but the text got all weird like stretched or something. Is there any attribute that I don't know about to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863974/android-textview-padding-between-lines

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android TextView padding between lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863974/android-textview-padding-between-lines)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use android:lineSpacingExtra="xxdp"

Answer (score 25):

Use android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2" or some number greater than 1