# Android TextView padding between lines

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView which displays a long text. I want to give some space between lines like in CSS with line-height property. How can I do it?

Answer (score 485, accepted):

You can use `lineSpacingExtra` and `lineSpacingMultiplier` in your XML file.

Comment: lineSpacingMultiplier works for me with float values like: android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"

Comment: Can you explain how these work? Where are these measurements taken from? Can you give examples with relation to the font and also language? For example, line spacing is measured from the baseline, but East Asian language have no baseline. Where is the default line spacing defined? Is it in the font itself?

Comment: For example: android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"

Comment: When I set text background, the background also covers the paddings.

Answer (score 105):

If you want padding between text, try `LineSpacingExtra="10sp"`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"/>
```

Comment: sp should be used instead of dp for this case

Answer (score 87):

you can look into `android:lineSpacingExtra` and apply it to your XML

[Additional Info is on this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingExtra)

or the related method `public void setLineSpacing (float add, float mult)`

[Additional Info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing%28float,%20float%29)

Answer (score 63):

This supplemental answer shows the effect of changing the line spacing.

[image]

You can set the multiplier and/or extra spacing with

```
textView.setLineSpacing(float add, float mult)
```

Or you can get the values with

```
int lineHeight = textView.getLineHeight();
float add = tvSampleText.getLineSpacingExtra();          // API 16+
float mult = tvSampleText.getLineSpacingMultiplier();    // API 16+
```

where the formula is

```
lineHeight = fontMetricsLineHeight * mult + add
```

The default multiplier is `1` and the default extra spacing is `0`.

Answer (score 21):

Adding `android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"` can make the line spacing to 80%.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `TextView.setLineSpacing(n,m)` function.

Answer (score 10):

You can either use `lineSpacingExtra` or `lineSpacingMultiplier` in your XML file.

`lineSpacingExtra` add extra spacing between lines of text of TextView

```
<TextView
    android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp" />
```

`lineSpacingMultiplier` works as scale factor for height of line space:

```
<TextView
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8" />
```

In other words, each line height will be `height * multiplier + extra`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2 attrs

---

**1. **lineSpacingExtra:****
it use for dp spacing

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
```

**2. lineSpacingMultiplie:**
it use for relative scale

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's working for me**

just add two lines to your Textview

> ```
>  android:includeFontPadding="false"
>  android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
> ```

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchByItemTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="@font/dm_sans"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
            android:paddingVertical="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            android:text="@string/date_of_birth"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
```

note: don't use  `android:textAppearance=""`

before :[image]

after: [image]

Answer (score 0):

As an extended answer to above solutions

Remember you can add `<item name="android:lineHeight">16sp</item>` for directly setting the line heights but as per the docs above line works like this -

```
Explicit height between lines of text. If set, this will override the values set for lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier.
        <attr name="lineHeight" format="dimension" />
```

So be sure to use either `lineSpacingExtra & lineSpacingMultiplier` or `lineHeight` and not both.

Answer (score 0):

As of 16/11/2021,
I use this line to increase the line space height:

```
android:lineHeight="25dp"
```

For me the other answers weren't helpful because maybe they updated the attribute and quite a lot of stuff changed in this version.