# How to set custom typeface to items in NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-design-library, navigationview

With the new `NavigationView`, we are able to set a drawer's items through a menu resource in XML.

With that, we can set each item with something like

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/drawer_my_account"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_account"
  android:title="@string/drawer_my_account" />
```

But now, I want to set a custom typeface to each of those items in my drawer, and I could not find a way to do that, either by XML or by Java code. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53379256/787399

Answer (score 171, accepted):

just add following class file to your project.

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

then create following method to your activity

```
private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ds_digi_b.TTF");
        SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
        mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("" , font), 0 , mNewTitle.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
}
```

and call it from activity.

```
navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
        Menu m = navView.getMenu();
        for (int i=0;i<m.size();i++) {
            MenuItem mi = m.getItem(i);

            //for aapplying a font to subMenu ...
            SubMenu subMenu = mi.getSubMenu();
            if (subMenu!=null && subMenu.size() >0 ) {
                for (int j=0; j <subMenu.size();j++) {
                    MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                    applyFontToMenuItem(subMenuItem);
                }
            }

            //the method we have create in activity
            applyFontToMenuItem(mi);
        }
```

and here is my output

[image]

Comment: In my answer there is no onGobalLayout ..Bcause i have use custom type face span .. because SpannableString allow formatting ..but don't allow to change the font for that i have use custom type face span class ..

Comment: Another alternative is [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33722998/4151208). It solves the problem of custom fonts and adds font caching--a very important thing to have if you're inflating fonts a ton of times.

Comment: Where is the method getAssets() defined? It looks like that is missing from the code above.

Comment: People who downvote. Please try to give the reason so that i can understand my mistake. And not only on my answer, On any answer if you donwvote give the reason.

Comment: Got this error This class implements Parcelable but does not provide a CREATOR field

Comment: What ?? This class is not parcelable .. plz check your code properly

Comment: TypefaceSpan implements ParcelableSpan. here's a generic creator field, but you'll need to add another constructor that takes the parcel "in" and calls super(in):         
    public static final Creator CREATOR = new Creator() {
        public HopstaTypeFace createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new HopstaTypeFace(in);
        }

        public HopstaTypeFace[] newArray(int size) {
            return new HopstaTypeFace[size];
        }
    };

Comment: @AdeelTurk Yes it gave me that error but I just removed that inspection. Code works like a charm +1ed.

Comment: I git This class implements Parcelable but does not provide a CREATOR field error. i'm not able to overcome

Comment: I use this approach for menu item in toolbar. All fine on android 5 but on 7 version it isn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Moinkhan: What, if I need to change font size as well?

Comment: font size is very small as normal ? why

Answer (score 80):

this one working for me

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="#4A4444"
       android:clipToPadding="false"
       android:paddingBottom="50dp"
       app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
       app:menu="@menu/drawer_home"
       app1:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle" >
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

res->values->styles

```
 <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

//to Set Custom Typeface MainApplication.java

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

//set Custom Typeface

        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "OpenSans-Semibold.ttf");
    }
}
```

// FontsOverride.java

```
public final class FontsOverride {

     public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
                String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
            final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    fontAssetName);
            replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
        }

        protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                final Typeface newTypeface) {
            try {
                final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                        .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
                staticField.setAccessible(true);

                staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: that's a really clean solution

Comment: It would really be perfect if it had anything to do with the question. We are talking about typeface, not font size. Check out the other answers really...

Comment: Hii iBobb i have updated answer as i know how to set Custom Typeface.Thanks

Comment: Perfect Answer. Simply awesome

Comment: Brilliant & clean.

Comment: No so clean, since using reflection to get to not accessible static field.

Comment: its using reflection, it will break in Proguard

Comment: Reflection is a worst way for any solution. as it this code can break on any future version of android.

Comment: not
`app1:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"` but `app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"`

Comment: This is a very clean and bug free working code. i am happy i have found this answer. Thanks Man. Acceped answer is buggy version.

Comment: Thanks @RamkeshYadav bhai, Appreciated your comment.

Answer (score 29):

Use the `app:itemTextAppearance` property and give it a custom style that you create in the `styles.xml` file of your app.

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bg_gradient"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationView"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationViewItemText"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer">
```

In `styles.xml` create this custom style overriding the `TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge`, as the [Material documentation suggests](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/NavigationDrawer.md#theming).

```
<style name="NavigationViewItemText" parent="TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: @chris838 , Its work if you follow this for adding your custom font : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Comment: This should be accepted as it is the most up-to-date solution!

Comment: Perfect solution. However if you are using custom fonts then use ```<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/custom-font</item>```

Comment: That's the way to do it. Override the `TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge` style instead of the `TextAppearance.Medium`, that's the right one, [as per the documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/NavigationDrawer.md#theming).

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a way to do it?

Yes. The [`NavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) doesn't provide a direct way of handling this, but it can easily be achieved using [`View.findViewsWithText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewsWithText(java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.view.View%3E,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)).

There are two things that will help us handle this.

1. Each `MenuItem` view is a `TextView`. So, that makes applying your `Typeface` that much easier. For more information on the `TextView` actually used by `NavigationView`, see [`NavigationMenuItemView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuItemView.java).
2. `NavigationView` [provides a callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html) when a `MenuItem` is selected. We're going to have to supply each `MenuItem` with a unique id and this callback will help generify those ids as much as possible, which means a little less code later on. Although, this is more related to whether or not you have a `SubMenu`.

**Implementation**

Notice each `MenuItem` id is simply `menuItem+Position`. This will come in handy later when we're finding the `View` for each `MenuItem`.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="MenuItem 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
        android:title="MenuItem 2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
        android:title="MenuItem 3" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
        android:title="MenuItem 4" />
</group>

<item android:title="Sub items" >
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuItem5"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Sub item 5" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuItem6"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
            android:title="Sub item 6" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

---

```
/** The total number of menu items in the {@link NavigationView} */
private static final int MENU_ITEMS = 6;
/** Contains the {@link MenuItem} views in the {@link NavigationView} */
private final ArrayList<View> mMenuItems = new ArrayList<>(MENU_ITEMS);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    final NavigationView navView = ...
    // Grab the NavigationView Menu
    final Menu navMenu = navView.getMenu();
    // Install an OnGlobalLayoutListener and wait for the NavigationMenu to fully initialize
    navView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Remember to remove the installed OnGlobalLayoutListener
            navView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            // Loop through and find each MenuItem View
            for (int i = 0, length = MENU_ITEMS; i < length; i++) {
                final String id = "menuItem" + (i + 1);
                final MenuItem item = navMenu.findItem(getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName()));
                navView.findViewsWithText(mMenuItems, item.getTitle(), View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);
            }
            // Loop through each MenuItem View and apply your custom Typeface
            for (final View menuItem : mMenuItems) {
                ((TextView) menuItem).setTypeface(yourTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You can see how using a generic `MenuItem` id allows you to utilize [`Resources.getIdentifier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and save a few lines of code.

**`SubMenu` caveat**

Something to keep in mind. You need to explicitly loop over your `N` menu items rather than using [`Menu.size`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#size()). Otherwise, your `SubMenu` items won't be recognized. In other words, if you don't have a `SubMenu`, another way of doing this would be:

```
for (int i = 0, length = navMenu.size(); i < length; i++) {
    final MenuItem item = navMenu.getItem(i);
    navigationView.findViewsWithText(mMenuItems, item.getTitle(), View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);
}
```

And you don't have to worry about applying a unique id to each `MenuItem`.

**Results**

[image: results]

The font I'm using in the example is: [Smoothie Shoppe](http://www.dafont.com/smoothie-shoppe.font)

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer.
- - - 
I see that your code works to set the custom typeface, but I don't feel comfortable with using `OnGlobalLayoutListener` and traversing the `ViewTree` that way, specially by using `getResources().getIdentifier(...)`: that is exactly why I asked for an `easy way`.

Also, this looks like you're relying on the items title to get the reference to them - this will make me a prisoner of my titles, right? I'd love to see a less coupled option.

Comment: You aren't going to get one. `NavigationView` simply doesn't provide an "easy" way to handle this. I wouldn't be worried about using the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` or using `Resources.getIdentifier` though. These things are safe to use and also used internally by the Android framework too. 

You would be a prisoner to your titles, yes. I'd love to see a less coupled option too. I like to imagine the design library will be a little more customizable in this aspect later on.

Comment: `findViewsWithText` fails to find views which are outside the screen bounds. Is it expected behavior?

Comment: As @user3161880 says, if your menu happens to go off the screen this technique will fail to style those menu items. My workaround was to wait until all the items were found with `if(mMenuItems.size() != menu.size()) { return; }` before removing the listener and styling them. This could be a performance concern but was fine in my particular case (only one extra call to `onGlobalLayout()` was needed).

Comment: When I try casting my MenuItem to a Textview it becomes null. Any idea why this is? I can change the text of it without problem before trying to typecast it.

Answer (score 10):

I have used `app:theme`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorMenuBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationViewTextAppearance"
   />
```

`styles.xml` :

```
<style name="NavigationViewTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/badscript_regular</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

A different way to set your custom font:

**1.** You can add your fonts in a "font" folder, and then you can use them in any TextView (or wherever you needed)

[image]

An example of font.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:font="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400" />
</font-family>
```

**2.** In your styles.xml file, you can customize your item text style with that font, and color, wherever you need (from @Moonis Abidi answer)

```
 <style name="NavigationText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_semibold</item>
    </style>
```

**3.** Now, you only have to specify this in your navigation view with **app:itemTextAppearance**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationText"/>
```

// -------------
Also, if you need to use this font from others TextViews, you can use it like

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"/>
```

Comment: this is best way for set font in android

Answer (score 3):

Not a custom typeface, but another way to change the navigation items' font. Create a layout named `design_navigation_item.xml`.

```
<android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/navigation_icon_padding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
```

Then change the fontFamily to the desired font.

Comment: And where to use this layout ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late to answer but I found a cleaner way to do it, so I would like to share.

- Make a custom view `NavFontTextView.java`:

  ```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;

  import utils.CustomFontHelper;

  public class NavFontTextView extends NavigationMenuItemView {
  Context mContext;

  public NavFontTextView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      mContext = context;
      setDefaultFont();
  }

  public NavFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      mContext = context;
      setDefaultFont();
      CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
  }

  public NavFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      mContext = context;
      setDefaultFont();
      CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
  }

  public void setDefaultFont() {
      CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, "fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf", mContext);
  }
  }
  ```
- Make a file called `CustomFontHelper.java`:

  ```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.res.TypedArray;
  import android.graphics.Typeface;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  /**
   * Taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16648457/75579
   */
  public class CustomFontHelper {
  /**
   * Sets a font on a textview based on the custom com.my.package:font attribute
   * If the custom font attribute isn't found in the attributes nothing happens
   * @param textview
   * @param context
   * @param attrs
   */
  public static void setCustomFont(TextView textview, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFont);
      String font = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomFont_font);
      setCustomFont(textview, font, context);
      a.recycle();
  }

  /**
   * Sets a font on a textview
   * @param textview
   * @param font
   * @param context
   */
  public static void setCustomFont(TextView textview, String font, Context context) {
      if(font == null) {
          return;
      }
      Typeface tf = FontCache.get(font, context);
      if(tf != null) {
          textview.setTypeface(tf);
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- Make a layout `layout/design_navigation_item.xml` (the name must be exactly the same):

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <custom_view.NavFontTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
  android:drawablePadding="10dp"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:paddingLeft="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
  android:paddingRight="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
  app:font="fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf" />
  ```
- Place your font file `SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf` in this path: `app/src/main/assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf`

You're good to go! This way, you can keep your main activity cleaner.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I really like this approach but it doesn't seem to work, because NavigationMenuItemView doesn't inherit from TextView.  Is there a missing step?

Answer (score 3):

I've refactored **@adneal's** answer to this. It loops over the menu items(without going into sub items, only top level items) according to the index instead of the id and sets the Typeface.

Replace ***rightNavigationView*** with your NavigationView and ***{TYPEFACE}*** with your desired TypeFace

```
final Menu navMenu = rightNavigationView.getMenu();
        rightNavigationView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ArrayList<View> menuItems = new ArrayList<>(); // save Views in this array
                rightNavigationView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); // remove the global layout listener
                for (int i = 0; i < navMenu.size(); i++) {// loops over menu items  to get the text view from each menu item
                    final MenuItem item = navMenu.getItem(i);
                    rightNavigationView.findViewsWithText(menuItems, item.getTitle(), View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);
                }
                for (final View menuItem : menuItems) {// loops over the saved views and sets the font
                    ((TextView) menuItem).setTypeface({TYPE}, Typeface.BOLD);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

for those who use @Moinkhan answer, for applying font to every part of your menus use that solution and for every header section use id.
your menu like this..

```
<item android:title="@string/others" android:id="@+id/nav_others">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:title="@string/contact"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

and solution like this..

```
navMenu = navView.getMenu();
    MenuItem item= navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_others);
    applyFontToMenuItem(item);
```

maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I really loved the solution of "Dragon who spits fire"'s but I didn't get the `textview`. This could be done by doing the following:

```
TextView textView = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_menu_item_text);

public class StyledMenuItem extends NavigationMenuItemView {
public StyledMenuItem(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public StyledMenuItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
        setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(true);
    }
}

public StyledMenuItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
        setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(true);
    }
}

private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProjectView);
    String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.ProjectView_projectFont);
    setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
    a.recycle();
}

private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
    Typeface typeFace = TypeFaceProvider.getTypeFace(ctx, asset);
    TextView textView = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_menu_item_text);
    if (typeFace != null && textView != null) {
        textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    }
}
```

design_navigation_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

style.xml:

```
<style name="Body1" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="projectFont">Quicksand-Regular.otf</item>
</style>
```

attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="ProjectView">
    <attr name="projectFont" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the font file in the `res/font/` folder to bundle fonts as resources, then You can change it using style resources. In your `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView" 
   parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
   <item name="fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>
</style>
```

Then apply it as a theme in your view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
   ...
   android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach:

A **[NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html)** has children called **NavigationMenuItemView**. A NavigationMenuItemView has two children. One is **[AppCompatCheckedTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatCheckedTextView.html)**.

Override **onLayout** method of the NavigationView like bellow and change [Typefase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) of the AppCompatCheckedTextView:

```
public final class NavigationViewWithCustomFont extends NavigationView{
    private final Context context;
    private Typeface fontFace;

    public NavigationViewWithCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        this.fontFace = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom){
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        final ViewGroup navMenuView = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
        final int navMenuItemsCount = navMenuView.getChildCount();
        ViewGroup itemView;

        if(fontFace == null){
            fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.BTrafficBold));
        }
        for(int i=0; i<navMenuItemsCount; i++){
            itemView = (ViewGroup)navMenuView.getChildAt(i);

            if(itemView instanceof NavigationMenuItemView ){
                CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)itemView.getChildAt(0);
                checkedTextView.setTypeface(fontFace, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BottomNavigationView bottom_nav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "--your customized font file--");
for (int i = 0; i <bottom_nav.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem menuItem = bottom_nav.getMenu().getItem(i);
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableTitle = new SpannableStringBuilder(menuItem.getTitle());
        spannableTitle.setSpan(font.getStyle(), 0, spannableTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        menuItem.setTitle(spannableTitle);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more information to your answer. Don't just dump code.

Answer (score -1):

```
applyFontToMenuItem(popup.getMenu().getItem(0));
private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Redressed.ttf");       
    SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
    mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, mNewTitle.length(),pannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
}
```

Comment: Add some information rather than dumping the code only and do format the answer.