# Android Navigation Drawer custom fonts

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am use Navigation Drawer from `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`, i need set custom fonts for menu item.
How can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450325/how-to-use-custom-font-in-drawerlayout-and-navigationview?noredirect=1#comment54688471_33450325

Comment: I try this solution, but only toolbar title apply new Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

In your navigation drawer adapter use this method for applying custom fonts to the textviews of the list

```
public static void setFont(Context c, TextView... tv) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                "font_name.ttf");
        for (int i = 0; i < tv.length; i++) {
            tv[i].setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
```

Store the font in assets folder. This is for multiple text views you can use same for just single textview by remove the for loop

Comment: I use android.support.design.widget.NavigationView. How i can get access in LIstView?

Comment: Put this Function in a global file And then you can access this function by using className like MyClass.setFont(context, textView)