# Changing fonts/typeface in android options menu

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar, typeface, android-optionsmenu

I'm trying to change typeface in an Android app. Everything works well except the MenuItems in OptionsMenu. 
Thanks to this link ([How to set custom typeface to items in NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668346/how-to-set-custom-typeface-to-items-in-navigationview)) I've modified my options menu fonts, but this solution only works for MenuItems which are "hidden" under the 3 dots

Image of the problem:

[image]

To clarify I'm using this bit

```
private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {
        SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
        mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("" , Font.LightExtended), 0 , mNewTitle.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
}
```

Comment: did you resolve this problem?

Comment: probably no, sadly I can't remember