# Set Typeface font on Menu item Navigation Drawer Menu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-typeface

I have a font file on assets-font and what i want to is set icons form this file to items on navigation drawer menu.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_med_record"
    android:title="some text"/>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_history"
    android:title="some text"/>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_emergency"
    android:title="some text"/>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_personal_data"
    android:title="some text"/>
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/grup2">

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_exit"

    android:title="Logout"/>

</group>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom typeface to items in NavigationView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668346/how-to-set-custom-typeface-to-items-in-navigationview)

Comment: I saw this but it changes only text not the icons ...

Comment: What do you mean with **it changes only text not the icons**.

Comment: It changes the text of item on navigation drawer  but the icon of item is empty

Comment: In your code above, don't have  icon. you need to add  `android:icon=` to your item menu to set icon.

Comment: yes i know but i want to get the icon from ttf file

Comment: The [iconics library](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics) does what you want, you can load a font and turn glyphs into drawables then put then as icons into your Navigation menu.