# How to add a circled counter to an item in a navigation drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, navigation-drawer

I'm referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43455170/12553303).

It worked, giving me count in front of cart in menu of navigation drawer, but how shall I make the counter TextView inside a circle?

What I want is:

[image]

What I get from the above link is that it only displays the text 2, not in a circle.

My code:

menu:--

```
      <item
        android:id="@+id/MyCart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Cart"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"

        />
```

activity:--

```
 val  slideshow =
        MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView!!.menu.findItem(R.id.MyCart)) as TextView
    //Gravity property aligns the text

    slideshow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    slideshow.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);                                                                                                                    slideshow.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    //count is added


    RetrofitClient.instancecart.listcart(token).enqueue( object :
        Callback<CartResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<CartResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"falied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<CartResponse>,
            response: Response<CartResponse>
        ) {

            val res=response
            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                val retro: String = response.body()!!.count.toString()

                slideshow.setText(retro) //retrofit api count

            }
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Edited your question to make it easier to find for people looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the answer you linked is outdated in some ways, but also has limited styling options for the TextView. So you can do this instead: setting an `actionLayout` instead of `actionViewClass`.

[image: screenshot of navigation drawer with circled counter]

First, create a circle drawable XML resource (let's call it `res/drawable/navdrawer_counterbackground.xml`):

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

Then create a layout for your counter. Let's call it `res/layout/nav_counter.xml`. The FrameLayout lets us add gravity around the TextView, so it can be centered vertically in the menu item. Note the TextView has an id of `counter`. The layout width and height of the TextView control the size of the circle.

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_counterbackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="99+">
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Assign this layout to your menu item:

```xml
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_itemwithcounter"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_whatever"
            android:title="@string/menu_whatever"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_counter"/>
```

Then in your Activity or Fragment, create a property for the TextView:

```
private lateinit var counterView: TextView
```

In `onCreate()`/`onViewCreated()` you can get the navigation view and use it to get your TextView reference:

```
val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
counterView = navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_itemwithcounter).actionView.findViewById(R.id.counter)
```

And you can update the `text` property and visibility of this `counterView` whenever you need to.

Comment: i dont have xml for textview ..i have declared         app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"

Comment: see above latest image ..i want a circle not oval

Comment: its is not giving me the circle no matter how i give dimensions like 10dp,20dp...it is still oval and 2 is displaying in very start of circle not in center

Comment: your 48 was giving error telling to change to 48F..i did fix...then app crashes      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference

Comment: OK, I figured out a way to do it and actually tested it this time. Answer revised. Sorry about that. I made the circle size 30dp, but I think it would look better with 20dp and then shrink the text size of the TextView's text if the number has more than 1 digit.

Comment: can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69311365/how-can-we-customize-an-crop-image-activity-using-ucrop-library