# how can we customize an crop image activity using ucrop library

Tags: java, android, android-layout, crop, ucrop

I'm using an    `implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'` library for cropping purposes

[image: crop example]

Can anyone tell how can we edit this above design? can we make a custom design (UI) for this?
Because the above UI is default when selecting image from gallery.

link: https://github.com/ravi8x/Android-Image-Picker-and-Cropping

Comment: You can import it as s module and then customize the UI in module as per your requirement

Comment: i think the questioner is asking how we can do that ...`Because the above UI is default when selecting image from gallery.` @Nitish

Comment: Yes @Wini , but the above mentioned UI is of library and sadly it doesn't provide method to customise it. Using it as a module seems to be the better option here to me to customise UI.

Comment: @Nitish what exactly the module you are refering to?

Comment: @Wini  I'm referring to [u-crop libray](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) and adding it as a project dependency 'implementation project(':ucrop')' instead of git/online version . This way we can edit the code at our local system.

Comment: @Nitish im getting error as A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Project with path ':ucrop' could not be found in project ':app'.

Comment: Does this help - [import external module in project](https://alexzh.com/import-an-external-module-in-android-studio/) , make your you download ucrop from the git and point to `ucrop` folder