# How to add text programatically to a drawer menu item?

Tags: android, xml, text, edit, drawerlayout

I have an online jokes app with a simple drawer layout.

When I launch the app, a PHP script gets new jokes(added from last visit) and counts them.

I want to add to the Menu item that displays the jokes the number of new jokes found, ex:3.( the menu item's text is "Meniu glume", I want to append it at the end with the number of new jokes)

How can I do this?[should display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TihhZ.jpg)

Comment: use custom listview with two textview's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NavigationView menu items with counter on the right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560663/navigationview-menu-items-with-counter-on-the-right)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NavigationView class to show the Navigation drawer, then you could use the attribute `app:actionLayout` of the menu item to show custom view in the drawer items.

Refer this answer for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33607630/4586742