# Navigation menu item "badge" vertically alignment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

[image]

Hello I'm using badge counter in navigation menu, but. I can't move to center vertically. I tried margin, height:match_parent but width shape not success.

( https://stackoverflow.com/a/33607630/4933464 )
Here my codes ( I use with shape ):

@drawable/menu_counter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#ec443e" />
    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

@layout/menu_counter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/menu_counter"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any update on same I am having same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Original DrawerLayout doesn't support badges. But there is a many useful library

**MaterialDrawer** : https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Screenshots aviable on github page.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a relative layout and add

android:layout_centerVertical="true"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:background="@drawable/menu_counter"
       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
       android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```