# How to show an indicator with a navigation drawer menu item

Tags: android, android-layout, menuitem, android-design-library, navigationview

I am trying to show a count indicator with some of the associated menu items.
How do I go about doing that? I tried creating TextView children for menu items, but they don't seem to work. Here's a mockup of what I am trying to achieve (see notifier next to the Gallery option)

[image]

Comment: Have a look here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560663/navigationview-menu-items-with-counter-on-the-right

Comment: Thanks... this really helped :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `NavigationView`

> NavigationView provides a convenient way to build a navigation drawer,
>   including the ability to creating menu items using a menu XML file.
>   We’ve expanded the functionality possible with the ability to set
>   custom views for items via app:actionLayout or using
>   MenuItemCompat.setActionView().

---

### Example

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```

### drawer_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item1"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

### **menu_item_layout.xml**

you can customize as you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Item text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi there. Some general advice about the quote device, which I see you are editing into other people's material as well as your own posts. It looks like the first item is a quote (i.e. the text within comes from a manual or a speech) and the other two are not. In markup this has semantic meaning, which is "someone else said this". If _you_ are saying it, it is not a quote - which would apply to the last two items here. It is not a general highlighter. Hope that helps!

Comment: @halfer can show me the link where is it mentioned, so I can refer it in a future edit?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, can you be more specific? If you want to read more about what I've said above, the [HTML blockquote](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=html+blockquote) has the exact same semantic meaning.

Comment: @halfer thanks that's the link I want. Will keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Not the best solution but it shows the only way you can do it in NavigationView. By the way I used `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"` as shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529346/1276636).

Answer (score 1):

you can create `FrameLayout` in which add your `Titile TextView` and above that your `Count TextView` as follows
t

```
<FrameLayout>
    <TextView></TextView> //your titile TextView
    <TextView></TextView> //your count TextView which has gravity of top right and circular background drawable
</FrameLayout>
```