# How to add badge on item in NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I just start to use new component android.support.design.widget.NavigationView , before this for navigation drawer I use standard listview but right now I start using new component navigation View and having problem to implement badge on item.
Does anybody now how to resolve this ?

Comment: Hi, please be more specific.  Do you have any code that shows the problem you're having?

Comment: I need to display a count to the right of the menu item?

Answer (score 16):

This can be done with following steps

**1. Adding "actionViewClass" attribute tot the navigation drawer menu**

After creating the ‘Helloworld’ app with Navigation Drawer, look for the file ‘activity_main_drawer.xml’ (i.e. youractivityname_drawer.xml)under the folder “Menu” in the project hierarchy view.
Identify the group item and add “app:actionViewClass=android.widget.TextView” as given below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>
```

**2. Declare the Navigation Drawer menu item and initialize the item with the badge value.**

In your main Activity, declare the menu item of the Navigation Drawer as given below

```
//Create these objects above OnCreate()of your main activity
TextView slideshow,gallery;

//These lines should be added in the OnCreate() of your main activity
gallery=(TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_gallery));
slideshow=(TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_slideshow));

//This method will initialize the count value
initializeCountDrawer();
```

initializeCountDrawer() can be called where ever it’s required. It can also be used to update the count or badge value in the navigation drawer menu item.

```
private void initializeCountDrawer() {
    //Gravity property aligns the text
    gallery.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    gallery.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    gallery.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    gallery.setText("99+");
    slideshow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    slideshow.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);                
    slideshow.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

    //count is added     
    slideshow.setText("7");
}
```

On adding the above method, run the app. Et voila !!
A simple badge count will be displayed on the ‘gallery’ and ‘slideshow’ menu item of the Navigation Drawer.

**Dynamic badge values**

If you need the dynamic badge values, like updating the value from an API call or SQLite database, create a reusable method and update it on the OnStart() or OnResume() method of your Activity.

Complete source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Hariofspades/NavigationDrawerLabel)

Comment: Nevermind. I was doing navigationView.getMenu().clear(); to reset the menus. Every time I do that I have to call
messagesTextView = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_messages));
to reset everything up so then it works.

Comment: Simply copied from https://android.jlelse.eu/android-adding-badge-or-count-to-the-navigation-drawer-84c93af1f4d9 No credit for him?

Answer (score 2):

You still have to use ListView to set a layout.

For using the NavigationView properties, my workaround was passing a SpannableString with a different background as new title of the MenuItem.

I known is not the best solution but it works as a counter quite well. Something like this:

```
NavigationView navigation = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
Menu menuNav = navigation.getMenu();
MenuItem element = menuNav.findItem(R.id.item5);
String before = element.getTitle().toString();

String counter = Integer.toString(5);
String s = before + "   "+counter+" ";
SpannableString sColored = new SpannableString( s );

sColored.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan( Color.GRAY ), s.length()-3, s.length(), 0);
sColored.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan( Color.WHITE ), s.length()-3, s.length(), 0);


element.setTitle(sColored);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already know for this solution, but if I use listview I lose some of great NavigationView funcionalities.

Comment: This solution dont use the Listview :)

Comment: @Marco how can I change this to use a circle as the background? I'm trying to replace BackgroundColorSpan to RoundedBackgroundSpan, but it isn't on center

Comment: take a look to the accepted answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701762/android-spannablecontent-with-rounded-corners), it works very well :)

Answer (score 0):

I you want to add an ImageView as a badge;

1- add actionView as below

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_my_menu"
  android:icon="@drawable/my_nav_icon"
  android:title="@string/my_name"
  app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageView" />
```

2 - in your activity class

```
val yourMenu = binding.navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_my_menu).actionView
(yourMenu as ImageView).setImageResource(R.drawable.my_drawable)
```