# Displaying multiple kinds of shapes behind text in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am currently facing an issue where I want to display a shape behind a part of text, and then a different shape behind the next part of text. I tried using multiple TextViews, but I did not know how to get them to show as if it was one text. I also tried using a SpannableString, but I couldn't make this work. To make this more clear, this is the way I want it:

[image]

My shapes are XML files, loaded as drawables.

The SpannableString code I tried is this:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc");
Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oval_background);
d1.setBounds(0, 0, d1.getIntrinsicWidth(), d1.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d1, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(ss);
```

But neither the text nor the background showed up here. Trying another drawable makes the drawable show up, but not the text.

This is oval_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

  <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:radius="60dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp" />

  <solid android:color="#1287A8" />

  <padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Now my question is, what is the best way to get my desired result?

Edit: Using the Flexbox as @R. Zagórski suggested, I come to this result:[image]

Which is an improvement, but it is not  yet finished. The Flexbox code I am using is:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexDirection="row"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:justifyContent="flex_start"
    app:alignItems="flex_start"
    app:alignContent="flex_start"
    android:id="@+id/flexbox"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_margin_small"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_margin_small"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_margin_small">

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your generated custom shapes into your textView by using background attribute. The main benefit of using custom shapes is to enhance the look by using gradient.

**Steps :**

1. Create a custom shape resource layout file for your View in drawable directory.

   `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <stroke android:width="2dp" 
   android:color="@android:color/holo_purple"/>
   <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" 
   android:endColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
   <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
   <padding android:left="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:right="2dp" 
   android:top="2dp"/>
   </shape>`
2. In the Layout file of TextView , add  attribute **android:background="*@drawable/yourshape*"** :

   `<TextView
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape1"/>`
3. This layout created following output , .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For applying background for `TextView` use `android:background` attribute like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724134/6507689) or when created programatically use `setBackground` method of `TextView`.
For arranging `TextView`s like you shown, use `FlexBoxLayout` from Google: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I looked into the Flexbox you suggested. I couldn't get it entirely the way I wanted it, but it is a step in the right direction. I edited the OP.

Comment: Well, I don't quite understand, where the problem exactly lies. Maybe You need to measure text width to divide longer text portions into smaller ones to fit one line? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18958569/6507689

Answer (score 0):

It's ease to done without any library. Here is working example

**UPDATED**

1. Define main method. Which will invoke creation View. (You can use you custom layout, or something else). And then create random shapes as background for view and color.

   ```
   /**
    * Max Width for all random text.
    * Should include margins of layout, etc.
    */
   private int getMaxWidthLine () {
       Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
       Point size = new Point();
       display.getSize(size);
       return size.x - 20;
   }
   /**
    * Parent of all Random TextView should LinerLayout with vertical
    * orientation, to apply building Views line by line, based on Width.
    */
   private void addRandomTextInLine (LinearLayout mainViewGroup, TextView textView) {
       LinearLayout lastTextHolder;
       if (mainViewGroup.getChildCount() > 0) {
           lastTextHolder = (LinearLayout) mainViewGroup.
                   getChildAt(mainViewGroup.getChildCount() - 1);
       } else {
           LinearLayout firstTextHolder = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
           firstTextHolder.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams
                   (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           firstTextHolder.addView(textView);
           mainViewGroup.addView(firstTextHolder);
           return;
       }
       mainViewGroup.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
       lastTextHolder.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
       textView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

       int maxParentWidth = getMaxWidthLine();
       int lastHolderWidth = lastTextHolder.getMeasuredWidth();
       int nextTextWidth = textView.getMeasuredWidth();

       if (maxParentWidth - lastHolderWidth >= nextTextWidth ) {
           lastTextHolder.addView(textView);
       } else {
           LinearLayout newTextHolder = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
           newTextHolder.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams
                   (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
           newTextHolder.addView(textView);
           mainViewGroup.addView(newTextHolder);
       }
   }

   /**
    * Start method, for generation TextView with Random Background
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   private void addRandomCornersText (ViewGroup group, String text) {
       /*
        * Just defining View programmatically.
        * You can use inflate from layout.
        */
       TextView itemText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
               (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
       int margins  = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);
       int padding = (int) (10 * scale + 0.5f);
       params.setMargins(margins, margins, margins, margins);
       itemText.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
       itemText.setLayoutParams(params);

       /*
        * Generate random shapes/corners and
        * applying this changes to the view
        */
       Random random = new Random();
       int r = random.nextInt(100);
       float[] outerR = new float[] {r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r};
       ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerR, null, null));
       shape.getPaint().setColor(Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256),
               random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));

       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
           itemText.setBackground(shape);
       } else {
           itemText.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
       }
       itemText.setText(text);
       addRandomTextInLine((LinearLayout) group, itemText);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Call, wherever you need your method. Which wil return random color and shapes TextView.

   ```
   ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_text_holder);
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
       addRandomCornersText(viewGroup, LoremIpsum.getInstance().getWords(1, 4));
   }
   ```

Than you will se something like below. But there also some additional impromevents, like adding invert color for TextView Text Color, some Width Settings, etc.

**EXAMPLES**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for taking the time to write this. I had something similar, but the issue I have is that if a TextView does not fill up the full width, a new one does not start. This is what I'm trying to accomplish. Once the complete width is taken up, the TextView should continue on the next line.

Comment: @user2988879 But what is the problem? Calculate screen width, and split to new Liner Layout if with is more then expected? Is it problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use android custom button generator, set backgrounds to buttons as per your choice