# Custom button with text and image

Tags: android

I'm looking for do a button like this preview :

[image]

I tried to do this with a button but my problem is that to put the border and the image I use android: background and I can not put the image and the border at the same time :/

Another problem for which I did not know how is a border to the text (which is simply the text of the button).

I wonder if I'm going in the wrong direction. I saw that there were button images but I'm not sure it suits me. Would there be a way to put a layout to a button?

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/mainButton1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
        android:layout_width="150"
        android:layout_height="150"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_green_500_48dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/mainButton" <-- or android:drawable="@drawable/image" how for put the both ? -->
        android:text="Text"
         />
```

**mainButton.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#00FF00"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

i have found many answers on Stackoverflow but the link to tutos was dead ...

Comment: What I'd try first is the double check if I can just put both of these image and button into a Layout and put the layout somewhere. The longer story would be to override ViewGroup (I think) or maybe a Button. Browse through the code of Button and see where you could tinker around.

Comment: basically you can use customized view (extends from a View class, and add TextView / ImageView in this view), then put your image into imageview and boarder into view's background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom `View` with desired background and `ImageView`,`TextView` inside. Then set `ClickListener` to it.

If you want background behind `TextView` you can use [SpannableString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724134/3416163) or just create XML drawable and set it as `TextView` background.

Here what i've done:

Button class:

```
public class CustomButton extends LinearLayout {

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflateLayout(context);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflateLayout(context);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        inflateLayout(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        inflateLayout(context);
    }

    private void inflateLayout(Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_button, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        makeSpannable(textView);
    }

    private void makeSpannable(TextView textView) {
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
        spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFF0021), 0, textView.getText().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(spannable);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

layout for CustomButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="CLICK ME!"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

background for button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#00FFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

What I've got:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these detailed explanations