# RecyclerView auto size column

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

***I would like to know is there have anyway to have autosize/stretch/autofit in `RecyclerView` like `TableLayout`?***

I have used `TableLayout` to present the data from database, but it's just too slow, took around 3+ seconds to show up the data.

And I have replace that with `RecyclerView`, it can show the data immediately, but it do not offer the `stretchColumns` options, and all text are squeezed.

Currently I have retrieve the maximum length of field from database, and calculate the possible width.  But this solution is not good enough, some column are too wide for the data. Here is my code:

**Layout for Recycler View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/data_recycler"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

**Layout for row**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/col2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ViewHolder**

```
private class ViewItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView col1;
    private TextView col2;

    ViewItem(View view) {
        super(view);

        col1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.col1);
        col1.setWidth(GetTextWidth(col1, columnWidth.get(0)));
        col2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.col2);
        col2.setWidth(GetTextWidth(col2, columnWidth.get(1)));
    }
}

private static int GetTextWidth(TextView textView, long stringLength) {
    String str = new String(new char[Integer.parseInt(stringLength + "")]).replace("\0", "W");
    return Math.round(textView.getPaint().measureText(str));
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286207/tablelayout-with-recyclerview/44402928

Comment: @JosephK. Nope, at the end I have changed it to another layout

Comment: Which layout is it? Layout does not matter for me. Just want to create a scrollable table view which auto sizing columns. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: @JosephK. I'm sorry I forgot the details, just whole layout changed.  BTW, for your question, you may try to calculate the longest string and set the column width with that (as stated in my question, not good, but useable)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question and you want do display items in several columns/rows with different sizes, you have to set LayoutManger in your case StaggeredGridLayoutManager for your RecyclerView.

```
int orientation = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL;
int spanCount = 2;
```

for vertical orientation spanCount is number of columns, otherwise if orientation is horizontal, spanCount is number of rows.

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(spanCount, orientation);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to have layout xml for row? Currently I using `LinearLayoutManager`.  Moreover, `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` can have same effect as `stretchColumns` in table layout?

Comment: Here is a pretty simple [tutorial](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/) that will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, as other tutorial I found, normally `StaggeredGridLayout` use for display some "island".  I haven't test this layout yet, but I think the result should be something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34251368/1050927).  However, I want to have something like datagrid, is there something I have missed?