# How to set line-height textView on Android

Tags: android

I give below attributes that I use textView in my application. ( Green text in middle )

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="10/9"
                android:id="@+id/estimate_fertility_date"
                />
```

However, there are spaces like the example picture. I want to set these spaces because when App initialize, It seems awful.

I have researched about 1 hour and I found some answers but They are not which I want answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6864017/2834196

[image]

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to do but if you can't seem to set the spacing as you'd like, maybe first add android:includeFontPadding="false" to your textview so that the default pading doesn't factor into the spacing you desire, then set top/bottom padding or margin to the textview...

Answer (score 5):

It 's not easy to get absolutely no text padding in a normal `TextView`. One way is to can set a minus margin for the `TextView`, or just use `textview.setIncludeFontPadding(false)` to reduce padding to some degree.

Comment: The only solution I found that actually did anything with my textview. But theres still some padding.

Answer (score 4):

Adding negative values to margin does it help you?

```
<TextView
android:layout_marginTop="-10dp" />
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked but I'm not sure that this approach is exactly correct. Altough I am giving you one point :)

Comment: Well, What if `TextView` contains multiple lines ? this is not a right solution. `lineSpacingExtra` would be the right option I think.