# What is the Android equivalent to CSS line-height?

Tags: android, css

My graphic designer instructed my team to format a text box with a 1.5 line height.

In CSS, I would express this as:

```
line-height: 150%;
```

What is the Android equivalent to the web `line-height` property?

**Duplicate?**

I think that this question is not a duplicate of [android textview padding between lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863974/android-textview-padding-between-lines), but rather a narrower question. The other one refers to line spacing in general, and this one refers to proportional, css-like spacing.

Comment: how do I convert 22sp "line height" requirement. to an android textView? makes no sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use **lineSpacingExtra** and **lineSpacingMultiplier** in your XML file.

From [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6864017/1624079)

Also consider reading  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: Thanks. The `lineSpacingMultiplier` is probably the exact equivalent. The direct link is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingMultiplier

Comment: lol. how can I do equivalent. formulas etc?