# How to add space at the start and end of eachline

Tags: android

I have created a custom textview class and I am using BackgroundColorSpan to apply color in the background. How can I add blank space before and after each line. I really appreciate any help.

```
final String test_str1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";


public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFont();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFont();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setFont();
    }

    private void setFont() {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/TEXT.ttf");
        setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);

        Spannable myspan = new SpannableString(getText());
        myspan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF757593), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        txtview.setText(myspan);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried .append(" ");

Comment: Are you asking about adding space as a character (" ") or as a blank space in layout?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863974/android-textview-padding-between-lines

Comment: @naXa add " " before and after each line .Basically adding more space to text.

Comment: @JaredRummler your question is about adding space between lines.

Comment: not between but start and end of each line and not line height.

Comment: Is it editable TextView? When do you want to add spaces: on text change, on focus lose, on other event?

Comment: What is `myString`? It is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply append or prepend a string with a whitespace in Java. In the first instance you should look for a library that does it for you.

I found [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to be a good one for string manipulations. It has class [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) with the following methods:

> [public static String appendIfMissing(String str, CharSequence suffix, CharSequence... suffixes)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#appendIfMissing(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence...))
> Appends the suffix to the end of the string if the string does not already end with any the suffixes.
>
> [public static String prependIfMissing(String str, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence... prefixes)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#prependIfMissing(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence...))
> Prepends the prefix to the start of the string if the string does not already start with any of the prefixes.

Both operations on `String` are null safe.

[Linking the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610727/adding-external-library-in-android-studio) to your project is easy. If you use Gradle just add this line to dependencies

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use JDK. `String.format()` can be used to left/right pad a given string.

```
public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
     return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);
}

public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%1$" + n + "s", s);
}

public static String pad(String s, int n) {
    return padRight(padLeft(s, n), n);
}

// Usage example
String myString = getText().toString();
Spannable myspan = new SpannableString(pad(myString, 1));
myspan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF757593), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txtview.setText(myspan);
```

References:

1. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391978/1429387) of methods used in this answer;
2. [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) | Java docs;
3. [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) | Android docs;
4. [CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) | Android docs.