# Android Textview altering line spacing/padding

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to create a textview within a bottomsheetdialog, with example layout as shown below. I've put my desired formatting notes in brackets 
Most of the spanned texts (bold, underlined etc.) are easy to create

Linespacing of 2 is easy with "\n\n", but how do I create 1.5 line spacing between certain lines? I'm adding text dynamically, using append(...), so I can't use the android:text atribute in the layout xml. Most of the examples I've seen have line spacing hard-wired into xml too which applies to all the text. I've found that you can apply different line spacings for paragraphs, but the "\n" would break the paragraph and the different line spacing won't work.

```
title (underlined, bold, very large)
(linespace 1.5)
blurb
(linespace 2)
sub-section1 (underlined, bold, large)
(linespace 1.5)
ClickableSubheading1 
(linespace 1.5)
clickableSubheading2
(linespace 1.5)
[could be many more subheadings here...]

(linespace 2)
sub-section2 (underlined, bold, large)
(linespace 1.5)
ClickableSubheading1a 
(linespace 1.5)
clickableSubheading2a
(linespace 1.5)
[could be many more subheadings here...]


etc - more subsections to be added as and when needed
```

NB: the clickable sub headings apply code implicit to the app, and are not hyperlinks (I thought about doing the whole lot as html and then reading that into my textview)
Basically, what I need is a span, or similar that says "put a linebreak, m times '\n' here", where 'm' can be any value

Comment: android:lineSpacingMultiplier='1.5'

Comment: for more information go through below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863974/android-textview-padding-between-lines

Comment: I think this would apply to all the text in the text view

Comment: yes do you want 1 textview with text variations?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I am asking for. Variations of double and 1.5 line spacing

Comment: Try finding some example of someone doing this with spannable strings

Comment: I have, with no luck. Thats why I am posting here.

Comment: have you tried using html text

Comment: Yes, I have, but then the problem becomes the clickable spans. They don't work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `RelativeSizeSpan` to scale the size of the second `'\n'` to smaller value.

Like

```
// I try to find all '\n\n' in TextView then I resize the second \n size to 0.5
private fun beautifulParagraph(textView: TextView) {
    val text = textView.text
    var startIndex = 0
    val sb = SpannableString(text)
    var index: Int
    while (text.indexOf("\n\n", startIndex).also { index = it } != -1) {
        sb.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), index + 1, index + 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        startIndex = index + 2
    }
    textView.text = sb
}
```

Using

```
beautifulParagraph(yourTextView)
```

XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_heelo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbnbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbnbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbnbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n\nccccccccccccccccnccccccccccccccccnccccccccccccccccnccccccccccccccccncccccccccccccccc\n\nddd"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"
/>
```

**Result** (without resize and with resize)

[image]
------>
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this i interesting. I didn't think Relative Size Span worked on "\n"?

If thats the case, I could do:

SpannableString string = new SpannableString("\n");
string.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0,1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: I tried it and it not working well. It quite hard to explain, you can try it then you will see the problem and understand why ^^. It work in different way to our expectation

Comment: The only problem I have with your solution is that my text is full of spans to show underline, bold etc. and onClick operator, and I don't know how well this post-processing of text would work.

Comment: I still dont understand why you can not apply. You know how to set multiple type span to 1 span, now just add 1 more type (RelativeSpan) to your current span. In my answer I write a function which easy to use for this case only but the basic idea just relativespan

Comment: Actually, it looks like I can use this, or a variation of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier in your XML
   file.
2. You can use Span to customize what you want in textview
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans
3. Or you can custom what you want in HTML and display HTML in TextView

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
   } else { 
       textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
   }
   ```

These what can i suggestion for you.

Comment: Wouldn't they be applied to all the text in the file? I need specific line spacing for certain lines.

Comment: @user3713442 I edited my answer, I added 2 another suggestions, I hope you find the answer of your question.

Comment: Hi but with your suggestion no 3 , In html formatting also how will take care of 1.5 line spacing?