# Font size in settings makes text in a TextView unreadable and overlapped

Tags: android, textview, overlap

Everything in the app looks fine until the font size is increased in the settings page on Android phones.

[Image of Text Before Font Size Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6d4r.jpg)

But as soon as the font size is increased in settings, the text overlaps each line.

[Image of Text After Font Size Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW79E.jpg)

Here's the code for the TextView

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_lyrics"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:minHeight="32dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:letterSpacing=".06"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineHeight="16dp"
            android:text="Abraham’s blessings are mine (bis) \nI am blessed in the morning, \nI am blessed in the evening,\nAbraham’s blessings are mine."/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453554/9722336

Comment: See if `autoSizeTextType,=uniform` also works

Comment: I've already tried using the lineSpacingMultiplier and the autoSizeTextType, nothing works :(

Comment: Try removing lineHeight attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in my code, I tried to use both the `android:lineHeight` attribute and the `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` attribute.

Don't use lineHeight for this type of problem, use lineSpacingMultipler or lineSpacingExtra.

Lesson learned :)