# Padding in textview in example.java

Tags: java, android

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
       sb.append(x).append("\n");
    }
   textView.setText(sb);
```

In the above problem the textView is printing 
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5

I am unable to print the number with paddingTop or paddingBottom like the below given example
**0 


1 


2 


3**

Please help me to achive the above target.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6864017/13373270.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending more than one `\n`.
Something like `sb.append(x).append("\n\n\n");` should do the trick